# Should "/users" and "/users/" point to the same (RESTful) resource?

Tags: http, rest

They do in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/) and probably any other website, but I'm not sure I understand why.

A popular analogy compares RESTful resources to <strike>files in the file system and filename `users` wouldn't point to the same object as filename `users/`</strike> static web pages and in a static website `users` would point to `users.html` and `users/` - to a different file - `users/index.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: they may only identify the same resource if one redirects to the other.

URI's identify resources, but they do so differently [depending on the response status code](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2005Jun/0039.html) to a GET request in HTTP. If one returns a 3xx to the other, then the two URI's identify the same resource. If the two resources each return a 2xx code, then the URI's identify different resources. They may return the same *response* in reply to a GET request, but they are not therefore the same resource. The two resources may even map to the same *handler* to produce their reply, but they are not therefore the same resource. To [quote Roy Fielding](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_2_3):

> The resource is not the storage object. The resource is not a
> mechanism that the server uses to handle the storage object. The
> resource is a conceptual mapping -- the server receives the identifier
> (which identifies the mapping) and applies it to its current mapping
> implementation (usually a combination of collection-specific deep tree
> traversal and/or hash tables) to find the currently responsible
> handler implementation and the handler implementation then selects the
> appropriate action+response based on the request content.

So, should `/users` and `/users/` return the same *response*? No. If one does not redirect to the other, then they should return different responses. However, this is not itself a constraint of REST. It is a constraint, however, which makes networked systems more scalable: information that is duplicated in multiple resources can get out of sync (especially in the presence of caches, which *are* a constraint of REST) and lead to race conditions. See Pat Helland's [Apostate's Opinion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pathelland/archive/2007/05/16/link-to-life-beyond-distributed-transactions-an-apostate-s-opinion.aspx) for a complete discussion.

Finally, clients may break when attempting to resolve references relative to the given URI. The [URI spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.3) makes it clear that resolving the relative reference `Jerry/age` against `/users/` results in `/users/Jerry/age`, while resolving it against `/users` (no trailing slash) results in `/Jerry/age`. It's amazing how much client code has been written to detect and correct the latter to behave like the former (and not always successfully).

For any collection (which `/users/` often is), I find it best to always emit `/users/` in URI's, redirect `/users` to `/users/` every time, and serve the final response from the `/users/` resource: this keeps entities from getting out of sync and makes relative resolution a snap on any client.

Answer (score 2):

> filename `users` wouldn't point to the same object as filename `users/`.

That is not true. In most filesystems, you cannot have a file named `users` and a directory named `users` in the same parent directory.

`cd users` and `cd users/` have the same result.

Comment: For the CLI they would be the same. For the browser, however, `users` could point to `users.html` and `users/` - to `users/index.html`.

Comment: Yeah it could, but it also could not. It all depends on server configuration and implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There are some nuances on this, while "users" represent one resource while "users/" should represent a set of resources, or operations on all resources "users"... But there does not seem to exist a "standard" for this issue.

There is another discussion on this, take a look here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186959/trailing-slash-in-restful-api

Answer (score 0):

Technically they are not the same. But a request for `/users` will probably cause a redirect to `/users/` which makes them semantically equal.

In terms of JAX-RS `@Path`, they can both be used for the same path.

Comment: When would it cause a redirect? Doesn't happen when I try.

Comment: No, only if the HTTP server is configure to do so.